# my code skips the if statement. (python 2.7)

Tags: python

Hi I'm very new to coding in python, but I can't find out why this code doesn't work.

```
prompt = "> "

def pos(answer):
    print answer
    if 0 < answer < 12:
        print "Damn you'r young, but you can still do a lot of things.\n"
    elif 65 < answer < 110:
        print "Wow you'r old, but never to old to learn something.\n"
    elif answer < 0:
        print "You should input a positive number."
    else:
        print "I didn't understand you, try inputting a number."


print "Hi there, what's your name?"
name_a = raw_input(prompt)

print "Hi %s, how old are you?" % name_a
age = raw_input(prompt)
pos(age)
```

For every input i give it will go to else and print "i didn't understand you...".

Comment: `raw_input` gives a string and you compare against a number

Comment: ok, so i should put: int(answer).

Comment: @JustHogenelst Use the built in `input` that returns an integer from prompt directly instead. Imagine when 3 of the answers use `int(raw_input())` instead of `input()` out of 4 answers, on stackoverflow. lmao

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using python 2 (there's no `raw_input` in python 3), `raw_input` returns a string. To get an integer from input, use `input`.

```
prompt = "> "

def pos(answer):
    print answer
    if 0 < answer < 12:
        print "Damn you'r young, but you can still do a lot of things.\n"
    elif 65 < answer < 110:
        print "Wow you'r old, but never to old to learn something.\n"
    elif answer < 0:
        print "You should input a positive number."
    else:
        print "I didn't understand you, try inputting a number."


print "Hi there, what's your name?"
name_a = input(prompt)

print "Hi %s, how old are you?" % name_a
age = input(prompt)
pos(age)
```

Side note: Use `int(input())` for python 3

If for some reason you want the code to run in both python 2 and python 3, try this

```
raw_input = input # since `input` exist in both python 2 and python 3
age = int(raw_input("..."))
```

Answer (score -1):

do

```
prompt = "> "

def pos(age):
    answer = int(age)
    print answer
    if 0 < answer < 12:
        print "Damn you'r young, but you can still do a lot of things.\n"
    elif 65 < answer < 110:
        print "Wow you'r old, but never to old to learn something.\n"
    elif answer < 0:
        print "You should input a positive number."
    else:
        print "I didn't understand you, try inputting a number."


print "Hi there, what's your name?"
name_a = raw_input(prompt)

print "Hi %s, how old are you?" % name_a
age = raw_input(prompt)
pos(age)
```

Comment: Why do `int(raw_input())`... what's up with people nowadays. Use `input`, please (in python 2)